# How to pass multiple commandline arguments to a script?

Tags: macos, script, command-line-arguments

I have a command line script that takes images as arguments. I got it working with one argument but fail to figure out how to pass in multiple.

Comment: to clarify: do you want to know how to pass them to the script, or access them from within the script?

Comment: Can you show us the script? If it's too long, cosider using a pasting service.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is like the following -

```
command img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg
```

But it is dependent on the script.